# Drupal migration - now only front page works

Tags: drupal, http-status-code-404

I just migrated a Drupal site from a ISP
to a dedicated Linux CentOS server.

MySQL Database is configured and generates front page without error.

Problem is that only the home page works.
All other pages show "404 Page Not Found Error".

So mysite.com/ works
but mySite.com/node/1 does not work.

I checked some obvious places:

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
is enabled in httpd.conf

Any ideas?

Answer (score 23):

I've had this happen before. It could be because your new Linux Centos OS server isn't configured for clean URLs yet.

Try to access the site as follows. To login:
http://example.com/**?q=user/login**

Login as admin and submit the form. You'll get access denied 404 page again after submission but still login.

Now manually type and go to http://example.com/**?q=admin/settings/clean-urls**

On this page turn off clean-urls and save and you should be able to access your site normally on the new server. Just configure it for clean-urls and then turn it back on when it's ready.

Comment: I appreciate this very much. In my install of D7 the clean urls page resides here: `/?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls`

Comment: Many Thanks for Jeff Hines and skålfyfan. I have got my site wrking. :)

Answer (score 3):

thanks Kevin,

mysite.com/?q=node/1? gives me a 404.

.htaccess was indeed missing. I copied in a generic version from a 
vanilla install into root directory (same directory as index.html) and this does not help.

(I don't have access to old site. We did not modify .htaccess - so I assume vanilla copy will do)

Comment: Try mysite.com/?q=node/1 without the trailing question mark. Including the question mark at the end will give you a 404. I think Kevin must have had a typo in his answer. Also, if you have no node 1 you'll get an error, so you might have to change the 1 to a number that actually exists in the node column within your database (nid column).

Comment: thanks calebD!  yes mysite.com/?q=node/1 works
however it works with or without adding .htaccess file.
Maybe I have to customize .htaccess.

Comment: I meant can you get there, as a question, not to actually put the second mark in, haha.

Comment: I added a htaccess from a clean drupal install and this fixed my install. thanks guys! :)

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility: If it's a new server, make sure that Apache has `mod_rewrite` installed. Happened to me.

Comment: After adding the .htaccess, I added this to Wamp and works ok now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have drupal 7 or higher use this for the clean-url config page:

> mysite.com/?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that the .htaccess file made it through the migration. Usually the culprit here. Can you get to *mysite.com/?q=node/1*?