# Unable to enable Clean URLs in drupal 7 website after migration

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7

Recently, I migrated my website from local machine to server machine. The website URL is http://www.example.com/myweb

I noticed that only front page is visible and other pages are showing 404 error.

After reading [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/6144/26927) answer, I got to know that this is happening because of clean URL module. I enabled `RewriteBase myweb` in .htaccess file but It doesn't work out. Finally I thought of disabling Clean URL temporary as told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4761399/1175065). This works well.

Now I wanted to enabled it again. It is showing following error-

```
Clean URLs cannot be enabled.
```

Below is the screenshot-

[image]

I can see some directory permissions error in status report at *admin/reports/status*. Are these related to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your Apache server setting on new server.

Enable 'LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so' line in httpd.conf file on your server and restart server

Answer (score 2):

Check if `.htaccess` works and also check if you have `AllowOverrides All` in your virtualHost config in Apache.